# Or and And Statements, Proper Method

Tags: python

So I have the code:

```
if bulletaloc == bulletcount or bulletbloc == bulletcount and bulletcount % 2 == 0:
        print("Ow!", paname + "'s guts were spilled all over the floor")
 if bulletaloc == bulletcount or bulletbloc == bulletcount and bulletcount % 2 == 1:
        print("Whoops!", pbname, "just got killed...")
```

And what i want it to do is when bulletaloc == bulletcount or when bulletbloc == bulletcount, AND, this applies to both conditions...When bulletcount%2 == 9, print the 1st message. So when either of the first two statements are true (bulletaloc... and bulletbloc..., AND the third is true, print the message.)
What ends up happening is, no matter what, both messages print! How do i fix this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should learn about precedence of `or` and `and`:

```
>>> True or False and False
True
>>> (True or False) and False
False
>>> True or (False and False)
True
```

I would refactor it like this:

```
if bulletcount in (bulletaloc, bulletbloc):
  if bulletcount % 2:
    print("Whoops! {} just got killed...".format(pbname))
  else:
    print("Ow! {}'s guts were spilled all over the floor".format(paname))
```

Comment: +1 for the refactoring, although I would be tempted to use `if bulletcount in (bulletaloc, bulletbloc)`. The two long conditionals in the OP are nearly identical, which makes it very hard to see exactly what's going on. This refactoring makes it quite a bit clearer.